# Cannot write a log file using slf4j with log4j

Tags: logging, log4j, slf4j

Im trying to write a log file using slf4j with log4j. I can see the logs in the console. but it is not written to the log file

Here is my log4js property file

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=D:\\loging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I have included slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar , slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5 and log4j-1.2.8.jar in my classpath.

Im using below method to write logs.

```
private static final String _CONSOLE_INFO = "_CONSOLE_INFO";

    public static void stdInfo( String message )
        {
            org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( _CONSOLE_INFO );
            logger.warn( message );
        }
```

Any help would me really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `LoggerFactory.getLogger( MyClass.class );` instead of your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can write logger object at class level like this.

```
public class MainDB {


private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MainDB.class);

public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException,SQLException{

         log.debug("Debug");
         log.info("Info");
     }

    }
```